# How to calculate the percent in linux

Tags: linux, parsing, awk

Sample input data:

```
Col1, Col2
120000,1261
120000,119879
120000,117737
120000,14051
200000,58411
200000,115292
300000,279892
120000,98572
250000,249598
120000,14051
......
```

I used Excel with follow steps:

1. Col3=Col2/Col1.
2. Format Col3 with percentage
3. Use countif to group by Col3

How to do this task with awk or other way in linux command line ?

Expected result:

```
percent|count
0-20%  |  10
21-50% |  5
51-100%|  10
```

I calculated the percent but i'm still finding the way to group by Col3

```
cat input.txt |awk -F"," '$3=100*$2/$1'
```

Comment: I calculated the percent but i'm still finding the way to group by Col3  `cat input.txt |awk -F"," '$3=100*$2/$1'`

Answer (score 2):

**awk** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    OFS="|";
}
(NR > 1){
    percent = 100 * $2 / $1;
    if (percent <= 20) {
        a["0-20%"] += 1; 
    } else if (percent <= 50) {
        a2 += 1; 
        a["21-50%"] += 1; 
    } else {
        a["51-100%"] += 1; 
    }
}
END {
    print "percent", "count"
    for (i in a) {
        print i, a[i];
    }
}' data
```

*Sample output:*

```
percent|count
0-20%|3
21-50%|1
51-100%|6
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic self documented. Need some fine tuning depending on group name in result (due to +1% or not but not the real purpose)

```
awk -F ',' -v Step='0|20|50|100' '
   BEGIN {
      # define group
      Gn = split( Step, aEdge, "|")
      }
   NR>1{
   # Define wich percent
   L = $2 * 100 / ($1>0 ? $1 : 1)
   # in which group
   for( j=1; ( L < aEdge[j] || L >= aEdge[j+1] ) && j < Gn;) j++
   # add to group
   G[j]++
   }

   # print result ordered
   END {
      print "percent|count"
      for( i=1;i<Gn;i++) printf( "%d-%d%%|%d\n", aEdge[i], aEdge[i+1], G[i])
      }
   ' data
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` with parametric bins and formatted output.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=\| -v bins='20,50,100' '
     BEGIN {n=split(bins,b)} 
     NR>1  {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
              if($2/$1 <= b[i]/100) 
                {a[b[i]]++; next}} 
     END   {print "percent","count"; 
            b[0]=-1; 
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
              printf "%-7s|%3s\n", b[i-1]+1"-"b[i]"%",a[b[i]]}' file

percent|count
0-20%  |  3
21-50% |  1
51-100%|  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, in GNU awk, using `switch` and regex to identify the values (since `parsing` was tagged in OP):

```
NR>1{
    switch(p=$2/$1){
    case /0\.[01][0-9]|\.20/:
        a["0-20%"]++;
        break;
    case /\.[2-4][0-9]|\.50/:
        a["21-50%"]++;
        break;
    default:
        a["51-100%"]++
    }
}
END{ for(i in a)print i, a[i] }
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -F, -f program.awk file
21-50% 1
0-20% 3
51-100% 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash:

```
# arguments are histogram boundaries *in ascending order*
hist () {
  local lower=0$(printf '+(val*100>sum*%d)' "$@") val sum count n;
  set -- 0 "$@" 100;
  read -r
  printf '%7s|%5s\n' percent count;
  while IFS=, read -r sum val; do echo $((lower)); done |
  sort -n | uniq -c |
  while read count n; do
    printf '%2d-%3d%%|%5d\n' "${@:n+1:2}" $count;
  done
}
```

Example:

```
$ hist 20 50 < csv.dat
percent|count
 0- 20%|    3
20- 50%|    1
50-100%|    6
```

Potential Issue: Does not print intervals with no values:

```
$ hist 20 25 45 50 < csv.dat
percent|count
 0- 20%|    3
25- 45%|    1
50-100%|    6
```

Explanation:

1. `lower` is set to an expression which will count the number of percentages less than `100*val/num`
2. The list of intervals is augmented with 0 and 100 so that the limits print correctly
3. The header line is ignored
4. The output header is printed
5. For each csv row, read the variables `$num` and `$val` and send the numeric evaluation of `$lower` (which uses those variables) to...
6. count the number of instances of each interval count...
7. and print the interval and count